# Paid version of my app doesn't show up on all phones on Google Play

Tags: android

I have four versions of a GPS tracking app on the Google play store at the moment. Using a desktop web browser you can view the four apps on the Google Play store when searching for "GPeaSe".

I have one free Lite version and the other three versions are Paid apps. Unfortunately, on some phones (I haven't discovered a pattern), the paid apps don't show up on their Google Play store. Strangely, my phone and my girlfriend's Samsung Galaxy S2 both don't work. (They both have custom ROMs).

Now, the Lite version requires a phone to work (it requires a cellular data connection). The Pro version doesn't, because it also functions as a "Viewer" app. Now, I've run the aapt badger command on both the Lite and Pro version to see the differences. Basically they are 100% identical in all version numbers, supported screen sizes etc. The only difference are some of the permissions.

Pro (Doesn't show up on everyone's Play store):

```
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION'
uses-permission:'android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.INTERNET'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.location'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.location.gps'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.location.network'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.touchscreen'
```

Lite (Shows up on all phones' Play store):

```
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION'
uses-permission:'android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.INTERNET'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.telephony'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.location'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.location.gps'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.location.network'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.touchscreen'
```

As you can see the Pro version also has the RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED permission, as it has the ability to launch on booting up of the device.

So what is causing my problem? The fact that one app is free and the other is paid? The difference in permissions?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you try giving the extra permission to one of your free apps, and see if that app still shows up? At least then you know if the permissions matter.

Comment: You mean I should try adding the receive_boot_completed permission to the free app?

Comment: Yes. Just try to see what happens, then change it back.